# Is there a more idiomatic way to generate an infinite sequence of uint64?

Tags: f#

```
let makeIdGenerator startvalue =
    let index : uint64 ref = ref startvalue
    fun () -> 
        let result = !index
        index := !index + 1UL
        result
```

What I need is a generator for a function which has type `unit -> uint64` as shown above.

The code above works but uses a reference variable to memoize the state of the generator.

Trying to use an infinite sequence as in `Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i)` does not work as the sequence inherently uses `uint32` for its state.

Does anyone here know a way to do this even without a reference variable? Maybe by means of recursion and yield or so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably I am not getting the question right, but what is wrong with `Seq.initInfinite uint64`

Comment: @olodnad The lambda for generating sequence value at index i is called with a 32 bit parameter. You cannot create 2^64 sequence elements with this. Only 2^32.

Comment: If you need to use lambda add type annotation in lambda. For example: `(fun (i:uint64) -> i)`

Comment: @Ptr https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370429.aspx <<-- ''Seq.initInfinite : (int -> 'T) -> seq<'T>'' Does not look like I can redefine that int to uint64 as else it would be Seq<'T,'X> and not Seq<'T>, right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Seq.unfold`:

```
let makeIdGenerator (startvalue : uint64) =
  Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some((i, i+1UL))) startvalue
```

Comment: But its uint32 in your case. Need uint64. Umm... does that work for uint64, too?

Comment: @user2225104 - Sorry, I thought the argument was meant to be `uint32`, see update.

Comment: Accepted this as it is cool. But one part of the problem still remains. Now I need to keep the state of the sequence somehow in application code.

Answer (score 6):

The standard functional programming approach to avoiding mutable state in a loop is to pass it in a parameter instead.

If you want an infinite sequence you can use a sequence expression with `yield` for the "first" result and `yield!` for the recursive call:

```
let genUint64() =
    let rec genFrom n =
        seq {
            yield n
            yield! genFrom (n+1UL)
        }
    genFrom 0UL
```

Comment: And then how to avoid having to fiddle with ``Seq.Head`` and ``Seq.skip 1`` in the code using this?

Comment: @user2225104 do you want some kind of patternmatching? Because you should not do this using seqs - try to use `map`, `filter`, `fold`, ... instead

Comment: If you actually just want a mutable generator of unique identifiers like you present in the question, then you don't necessarily want to use a sequence in the first place as then you need to thread it around or use mutation anyway.